# creating a RegEx of a specific input (ex. CT10-0001) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a hard time in creating a RegEx of a specific input (ex. CT10-0001) in javascript
I'm trying this regex example but not working. Any idea? tyia.

```
var regex = /^[CT]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}-?[0-9]{5}$/;
```

Comment: because in last you have 4 digits, not `5'

Comment: still not working, am i using a correct syntax?

Comment: Your syntax is fine @Jes

Comment: @Jes check the answer below and run the snippet.

Comment: i'm trying to validate the input onkeyup event but that doesn't work, so i reside in using onfocusout, and it worked :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match, `CT10-0001`, your regex should be:

```js
    var regex = /^[CT]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}-?[0-9]{4}$/;
    var str = "CT10-0001"
    console.log(str.match(regex))
```

You have 4 digits in end, you have used `{5}` instead of `{4}`.

You can also use `\d` to match digit instead of `[0-9]`.

```
var regex = /^[CT]{1,2}\d{1,2}-?\d{4}$/;
```

Comment: @Jan yes, i already edited my answer to add just that. First I just wanted to correct the small mistake in his appraoch and then suggest the improvement :)

Comment: @Jes: Consider accepting it then (green tick on the left). Don't forget tu upvote either.